# Extract string between the last occurrence of a character and a fixed expression

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a set of strings such as

```
mystring
[1] "RData/processed_AutoServico_cat.rds"
[2] "RData/processed_AutoServico_cat_master.rds"
```

I would like to retrieve the string between the last occurrence of a underscore "_" and ".rds"

I can do it in two steps

```
str_extract(mystring, '[^_]+$') %>% # get everything after the last '_'
    str_extract('.+(?=\\.rds)') # get everything that preceeds '.rds' 
[1] "cat"    "master"
```

And there are other ways I can do it.

Is there any single regex expression that would get me all the characters between the last occurrence of a generic character and another fixed expression?

Regex such as

```
str_extract(mystring, '[^_]+$(?=\\.rds)')
str_extract(mystring, '(?<=[_]).+$(?=\\.rds)')
```

do not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[^_]+$(?=\.rds)` pattern matches 1+ chars other than `_` up to the end of the string, and then it requires `.rds` *after* the end of  string, which is impossible, this regex will never match any string. `(?<=[_]).+$(?=\.rds)` is similar in that regard, it won't match any string, it just starts matching once it finds the first `_` and will come to the end of string trying to find `.rds` after it.

You may use

```
str_extract(mystring, "[^_]+(?=\\.rds$)")
```

Or, base R equivalent:

```
regmatches(s, regexpr("[^_]+(?=\\.rds$)", s, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7zk5F7/1)

**Pattern details**

- `[^_]+` -  1 or more chars other than `_`
- `(?=\.rds$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `.rds` at the end of the string immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5B%5E_%5D%2B(%3F%3D%5C.rds%24)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we get the `basename` and use `sub` to capture the word before the `.` followed by the characters that are not a `.` till the end (`$`) of the string and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*_(\\w+)\\.[^.]+$", "\\1", basename(mystring))
#[1] "cat"    "master"
```

If it is a fixed character

```
sub(".*_(\\w+)\\.rds", "\\1", basename(mystring))
```

---

Or using `gsub`

```
gsub(".*_|\\.[^.]+$", "", mystring)
#[1] "cat"    "master"
```